# Bitmap.compress png 8-bit pallete

Tags: android, png

I'm playing with sending some images over a Bluetooth link to an embedded device. The device speaks and decodes PNGs for the images, however it seems some of the messages are getting too large for transfer over the wire at a reasonable speed / data size.

I'm currently using `Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.Compression.PNG, 0, <ByteArrayOutputStream>)` to get the byte array for the compressed data.

Is there any way I can either make `Bitmap.compress()` be lossy with the colors. And for that matter, would Bitmap.compress ever use a 256-colour mode on it's own, given an image that has an appropriate number of colors.

Comment: i used `Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.Compression.WEBP, 75, <ByteArrayOutputStream>);` to get a reducion of 10% from the size of the PNG - depends on your data of course...